# Время выполнения цикла в функции и вне её

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Почему в JS внутри функции код работает быстрее в 2 раза, чем если бы он был выполнен не внутри функции?

```js
console.time('loop');
var i = 0;
for (i; i < 1000000; i++) {}
console.timeEnd('loop');

(function() {
  console.time('loop');
  var i = 0;
  for (i; i < 1000000; i++) {}
  console.timeEnd('loop');
})()
```

Comment: _почему в_ что?

Comment: Поправил, 0


Почему в JS внутри функции код работает быстрее в 2 раза, чем если бы он был выполнен не внутри функции?

Comment: Нужно смотреть во что это все развернулось, вполне возможно, что движки просто выкидывают цикл

Comment: @Grundy я тут попробовал увеличивать число итераций на несколько порядков — задержка тоже увеличивалась в обоих случаях, похоже не выкидывают (как минимум в Firefox)

Comment: А если заставить сделать в цикле полезную работу, которую точно тяжело выкинуть\оптимизировать результат будет еще интереснее!

Comment: Будет в любом случае внутри функции быстрее ?

Comment: @andreymal, поэтому я и говорю, надо смотреть что конкретно в итоге выполняется :-) в v8 вроде есть что-то для отладки, чтобы посмотреть bytecode итоговый

Comment: @GreySpan, все зависит от того, что конкретно будет выполняться

Comment: @andreymal, замена var на let в глобальном случае в хроме убыстряет в два раза :-)

Comment: @Grundy это ведь вполне логично, да? Нет необходимости писать в глобальный объект

Comment: @smellyshovel, именно. Но все равно интересно было бы посмотреть, что и как выполняется

Comment: @Grundy так может это и есть ответ на вопрос? В случае с функцией-то перезаписывается только переменная локальная, а там, где цикл в глобальном коде, приходится и глобальное свойство каждый раз обновлять

Comment: Если добавить в тело цикла `let r = i*Math.random()`, то скорость выполнения будет зависеть от порядка следования данных блоков. Второй будет быстрее.

Comment: @smellyshovel, подозреваю не все так просто :-)

Comment: @Grundy упомяните, пожалуйста, как разберетесь. Тема интересная, боюсь, потеряю

Comment: @smellyshovel тесты показывают, что возможно, вы правы. Переменная в глобальном контексте обновляется медленнее.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko сейчас бежать надо, если не сложно, попробуйте провести такой тест, при котором переменная внутри функции тоже будет ссылаться на глобальный объект. По идее время одинаковым должно быть

Comment: @smellyshovel так и сделал. Время действительно +- одинаковое.

Answer (score 7):

Ответ не претендует на 100% правильный. Проверено только в хроме.

Как предположил @smellyshovel в комментариях, причина в глобальном контексте. В первом случае мы меняем значение переменной, которая создана в глобальном объекте `window`. Во втором случае меняем локальную переменную.

Если во втором случае менять глобальную переменную, то время выполнения будет приблизительно одинаковым. Разница зависит уже от положения блоков. Второй исполняемый будет быстрее.

```js
console.time('loop');
var i = 0;
for (i; i < 1000000; i++) {}
console.timeEnd('loop');

(function() {
  console.time('loop');
  i = 0;
  for (i; i < 1000000; i++) {}
  console.timeEnd('loop');
})();

// а тут еще интереснее
(function() {
  console.time('loop');
  window.i = 0;
  for (window.i; window.i < 1000000; window.i++) {}
  console.timeEnd('loop');
})();

var o = {
  i: 0
};
// и тут тоже интересно
(function() {
  console.time('loop');
  o.i = 0;
  for (o.i; o.i < 1000000; o.i++) {}
  console.timeEnd('loop');
})();

// и тут самое интересное!
(function() {
  console.time('loop');
  window.o.i = 0;
  for (window.o.i; window.o.i < 1000000; window.o.i++) {}
  console.timeEnd('loop');
})();
```

Comment: Здорово, +1! Осталось только окончательного вердикта т-ща @Grundy дождаться (если он еще не забил), тогда можно будет спать спокойно :)

Comment: в последнем случае больше из-за того, что сначала ищется `window`, и только потом внутри него ищется `i`, в остальных случаях не нужно идти в сам объект

Comment: А в последнем почему переменная `o`, а устанавливается 0 через `window`?

Comment: @Grundy опечаточка

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko почему всегда переменные однобуквенные ??  

Comment: @Избытоксусликов привычка - экономлю место! :D

Comment: ладно лови плюс :)